# Is Jax the highest member of all the SOA charters?

Tags: sons-of-anarchy

It seems that when interacting other charter members, even presidents, Jax is given a type of respect meant for a superior. Several times he has given orders to other charters or easily convinced them to take on a task.

We know that

- Charming was the first charter
- J.T. was the founder
- Jax is J.T.'s son

So is Jax so well regarded because of this or does he hold some higher rank/seniority because he leads the Charming charter?

Answer (score 5):

His father is the founder of SAMCRO and its former President. Following his death, Clay became President. Jax was devoted to SAMCRO and dropped out of school to ensure this happened. He became a fully fledged member in 1995. Then, at some *unknown* time, he became the *Vice President*.

This is the position he held from the start of the series, until the Season 4 finale, when he threatened Clay and told him to step down, thus making himself President (from the episode *To Be, Act Two*. To quote from him in that episode:

> "You killed my father and Piney, you tried to kill Tara You're done
>   telling me anything, now I tell you."

***So he became the President and thus highest ranking member of SAMCRO***, from midway through the Season 4 finale onwards. Until then served as the Vice President.

For more information, have a browse through the incredibly detailed [wiki](http://sonsofanarchy.wikia.com/wiki/Jax_Teller) page.

**Edit:**

As to why SAMCRO is the *highest ranking* of all the charters - in the Pilot episode, we see Jax find [a manuscript](http://sonsofanarchy.wikia.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Death_of_Sam_Crow:_How_the_Sons_of_Anarchy_Lost_Their_Way) detailing the original vision of the Nine Founders when they set up SAMCRO. In other words, it was the *first* charter, i.e. the "mother charter". Their intentions can also be seen in the Pilot's [manuscript](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Sons_of_Anarchy_1x01_-_Pilot.pdf), which speaks of them as being the Founders throughout. Finally, the name of the organisation, SAMCRO, also indicates their status - *Sons of Anarchy, Redwood Original Charter*).

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in my question. I meant all of the charters of SOA, not just SAMCRO. Ignore my previous comment about your answer being incomplete.

Comment: @DustinDavis: He should be. They mentioned a few times that SAMCRO is the "mother charter" of all the clubs.

Comment: @DustinDavis: Will their name count? (Sons of Anarchy, Redwood *Original Charter* AKA SAMCRO?). The [script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Sons_of_Anarchy_1x01_-_Pilot.pdf) for the pilot also discusses it a few times

Comment: I'll add this instead of making it a separate answer; his father founded Sons Of Anarchy.  "SAMCRO" is an acronym for Sons (of) Anarchy Motorcycle Club - Redwood (CA) Original.  It's just a further designation that Redwood is the original charter.  Still further, the patch "Original 9" was worn by Clay, John Teller, Piney and the other 6 that formed the club.  The fact that Jacks is the current President of the "mother club" and son of the mother club's founder does give him some extra weight.

Comment: The problem with your answers is while they're obviously right, it's still just speculation. Where does it state that the original charter is "better" than the others? That's what I'm asking for. Either from the show or other official/semi-official sources.

Comment: @DustinDavis: Other charters respect SAMCRO (as the founding charter) for the same reason that members respect John Teller (as a founding member). The idea is the same; it's a recurring human behavior to show respect to one's _roots_. "Better" is a vague and subjective argument. "Respected" would be more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

Jax is the president of the Mother Charter (SAMCRO) thus making him the National President of the entire club. So yes he does have a certain sway over everybody!

Comment: This is just a lazy dupe of the answer above.